# Need to identify overlapping dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find overlapping dates for a table.  So the basic structure is ID, PFX, Start date, and end date.  So where the PFX for a given ID is overlapping with another PFX for each ID.

I tried this and had no luck.  https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/how-to-extract-overlapping-date-ranges-from-a-table-of-date-ranges

The highlighted is what I would want to show as an overlap.

[image]

```
Drop table #zzz_Overlapping
CREATE TABLE #zzz_Overlapping(

    [ID] [varchar](500) NULL,

    [PFX] [varchar](500) NULL,

    [EFF_DT] [datetime] NULL,

    [TERM_DT] [datetime] NULL

) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

insert into #zzz_Overlapping (ID,PFX,EFF_DT,TERM_DT)

values ( 123,'ABDM','1997-06-01','9999-12-31')

insert into #zzz_Overlapping (ID,PFX,EFF_DT,TERM_DT)

values ( 123,'ABDM','1997-10-01','9999-12-31')

insert into #zzz_Overlapping (ID,PFX,EFF_DT,TERM_DT)

values ( 123,'CSM1','1997-11-01','9999-12-31')

insert into #zzz_Overlapping (ID,PFX,EFF_DT,TERM_DT)

values ( 123,'CSM1','1998-01-01','9999-12-31')

insert into #zzz_Overlapping (ID,PFX,EFF_DT,TERM_DT)

values ( 123,'ABDD','1999-01-01','9999-12-31')

insert into #zzz_Overlapping (ID,PFX,EFF_DT,TERM_DT)

values ( 417,'CSM1','2001-06-01','9999-12-31')

insert into #zzz_Overlapping (ID,PFX,EFF_DT,TERM_DT)

values ( 417,'CSM1','2001-10-01','9999-12-31')

insert into #zzz_Overlapping (ID,PFX,EFF_DT,TERM_DT)

values ( 417,'CSM2','2001-11-01','9999-12-31')

select * from #zzz_Overlapping

select CONCAT(ID, PFX) FROM #zzz_Overlapping

SELECT A.*

FROM #zzz_Overlapping A

JOIN #zzz_Overlapping B

    ON B.ID = A.ID

    AND ((A.EFF_DT BETWEEN B.EFF_DT AND B.TERM_DT)

    OR (A.TERM_DT BETWEEN B.EFF_DT AND B.TERM_DT))

WHERE B.EFF_DT != A.EFF_DT OR B.TERM_DT != A.TERM_DT;


SELECT A.ID, A.PFX, A.EFF_DT, A.TERM_DT, B.PFX, B.EFF_DT, B.TERM_DT

FROM #zzz_Overlapping A

INNER JOIN #zzz_Overlapping B

    ON B.ID = A.ID

    AND B.EFF_DT < A.TERM_DT

    AND A.EFF_DT < B.TERM_DT
    AND A.EFF_DT < B.EFF_DT;
```

Added this for some clarification of expected result.
[image: Desired outcome would show the 3 rows would be overlapping. The keys are the ID AND PFX.]

Comment: What is the desire output? Because if you have A overlap with B and A overlap with C and show A, B, C you won't know who overlap with whom.

Comment: Also elaborate what mean `with another PFX for each ID.` because in your sample there is only one so we are not sure how to  handle with multiple overlaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improving upon the answer by Gordon, Can you check the following

```
with data
  as (select row_number() over(order by (select null)) as rnk
            ,*
         from #zzz_overlapping
      )
select o.*
  from data o
 where exists (select 1
                 from data o2
                where o2.id = o.id and
                    o2.PFX = o.PFX and
                    o2.EFF_DT <= o.TERM_DT and
                    o2.TERM_DT >= o.EFF_DT and
                    o2.rnk <> o.rnk
             )
```

dbfiddle link.
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=11f4e9dc6bd96df6f0c8145df0b953a8

Comment: So I wasn't understanding the problem correctly.  There is actually a 2nd table that the overlaps can occur off of.  It's not within the one table.  Also there is a crosswalk between the 2 tables.  So A could equal A but also B could equal C to determine the overlaps, there is a crosswalk.  I'm wondering if the same logic can be used from above?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want:

```
select o.*
from #zzz_Overlapping o
where exists (select 1
              from #zzz_Overlapping o2
              where o2.id = o.id and
                    o2.prefix = o.prefix and
                    o2.eff_dte < o.end_dte and
                    o2.end_dte > o.eff_dte
             );
```

Comment: When I do that it's not returning my desired result.  I see stuff in the output does not overlap.  An overlap would be ID and PFX like you said above along with any overlap in data spans.  So 123 and ABDM would be overlap on rows 1 and 2 of the output.  I would not expect 417 and CSM2 to show as an overlap since there is not another ID and PFX combination like that where the dates overlap.  Each date span should be compared to any other where the ID and PRX also match it.  I hope that makes sense and helps.